# Solution to a "dynamic"/"unstable" ahk_class name?

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotKey, `ahk_class NAME` has been a good identifier for programs. Typically, I now use it in the following two ways:

1. Simply calling the most recently called active instance:

```
    ; Pressing Win+Shift+X will bring up (or switch to) the Windows Journal
    Application
    #+x:: 
    IfWinExist ahk_class JournalApp
        WinActivate ahk_class JournalApp
    else 
        Run C:\Program Files\Windows Journal\Journal.exe
    return
```

2. Grouping windows with the same `ahk_class` and looping through them:

```
    GroupAdd, FIRE, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass

    ; Pressing Win+3 will go through all open Firefox windows one by one.
    #3::
    IfWinExist ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
        GroupActivate, FIRE, r
    else
        Run firefox
    return
```

However, there are certain programs that do not have a *stable* `ahk_class` name. For example, the ArcMap.exe should
display the following information in the "Windows Spy" window of AHK:

```
>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
Untitled - ArcMap
ahk_class Afx:012F0000:b:00010003:00000006:001C0BB0
```

Any idea how could I refer to this application that has dynamic `ahk_class`?

I am aware that there is also something called `ahk_exe`. However, I did not find it compatible with the method `GroupAdd`,
`GroupActivate` or `IfWinExist`.

Comment: What version of Autohotkey are you using ? `msgbox % A_AhkVersion` as ahk_exe needs v1.1.01+ http://ahkscript.org/download/ahk-install.exe

Comment: @blackholyman, thank you! You are right. I am running v1.0.*** version. Updating the AHK distribution in the background solves all the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely are on the right track trying to incorporate `ahk_exe`. `GroupAdd` (and every other command receiving a [`WinTitle` parameter](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) at that) **is** compatible with `ahk_exe` in AHK_L; this sample code works perfectly on my machine:

```
GroupAdd, notepad, ahk_exe notepad.exe
Run, notepad.exe
WinWaitActive, ahk_group notepad
Sleep, 1000
WinClose, ahk_group notepad
```

I suspect you're not using the most recent version of AHK. Get it [here](http://ahkscript.org/download/) and have another try.

Comment: Thank you for testing out. Updating the background application solves the problem. Though, the link to the download page goes as follows:http://ahkscript.org/download/